# Keyhandler cannot detect key

Tags: c#, xna

Hello I got a problem with my keyhandler. I pretty much want a function to detect if a key is pressed.

```
public bool keyHandler(Keys key)
    {
        if(key != null) {

            if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys() == key)
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false; 
            }
        } else {  return false; } 
    }
```

The problem lies with

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys() == key)
```

I don't know how to how to check if a certain key is pressed and how to pass that key in the function.

The error I get: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to oparands of type Microsoft Xna.Framework.Input.Keys[] and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys"
Using C# and XNA

I don't get why this doesn't work.. Can some one help me?

Comment: Operands of type *what*? Please don't truncate the error message...

Comment: I don't remember XNA API, but looks like `GetPressedKeys` is collection. Maybe `...GetPressedKeys().Contains(key)'?

Comment: Jon Skeet sorry about that, I've updated the post.

Comment: @user2879055 that fixes it, but that's not a good solution at all! Read the answers, they're much better solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys()` returns an array of Keys(`Keys[]`). It basically gets all the pressed keys, this is handy if you have some sort of keymanager or for a textbox or something.

What you need is something like this(Like Sebastian L said):

```
KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState(); // get the keyboard's state
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
  DoSomeReallyInterestingStuff();
}
```

`ks.IsKeyDown(Keys key)` returns true if the key is down.
So here's a better method:

```
class InputManager
{
   KeyBoardState state;

   // call every update
   public void Update()
   {
      state = Keyboard.GetState();
   }

   public bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
   {
      return state.IsKeyDown(key);
      // or return key == null ? false : state.IsKeyDown(Keys.key);
      // but you would never call this method with a null key, that'd be stupid.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetState()`  for a new object ;)

```
 KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
 MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

 if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
 {
     DoWhatEver();
 }

 if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
 {
     AnimateShooting();
 }
```